# Turn header-delimited sequences of paragraphs into Bootstrap panels with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web page where the HTML is generated from Markdown, and I'd like to achieve the following using jQuery without adding any HTML/Markdown (e.g. classes, ids...) to the page.

My current HTML consists of an *arbitrary number of* `p`s that follow `h4`s, which looks like the following:

```
<h4>Foo</h4>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<h4>Bar</h4>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>

<h4>Baz</h4>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

What I'd like to achieve, in as little jQuery code as possible, is to turn that into the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Foo</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Bar</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Baz</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What jQuery code can accomplish this?

Some constraints:

- Any number of `p`s can follow an `h4`.
- Nothing else but `p`s follow an `h4`; e.g. you never get an [`h4`, `p`, `p`, `div`, `p`].
- There are no other `h4`s anywhere else on the page, outside of this content.
- There are other `p`s elsewhere on the page (e.g. header, footer).
- Anything but a `p` can follow the final [`h4`, `p`, `p`, ...] sequence.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work: select all the h4 tags loop through each, and wrap the elements in the required div tags. Hope this helps! let me know if you have any questions.

```
// selecet all h4 tags, loop through each 
$("h4").each(function(){
  // variable b being h4 tags next element
  var b=$(this).next(); 
  //replace h4 with div tag and panel classes
  $(this).replaceWith("<div class='panel-heading  wrapgroup'>"+$(this).text()+"</div>");

  // While loop to check the p tags followed by h4 
  while(check){
    if(b.is("p")){
      $(b).addClass("wrapgroup wrapgroupptag");
      b = $(b).next();
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }

  //.wrapgroup will mark h4 and p tags and is replaced with panel tags
  $(".wrapgroup").wrapAll("<div class='panel panel-default'></div>");

  //.wrapgroupptag will mark all the p tags next to h4 
  $(".wrapgroupptag").wrapAll("<div class='panel-body'></div>");

  // remove all the classes 
  $(".wrapgroup").removeClass("wrapgroup");
  $(".wrapgroupptag").removeClass("wrapgroupptag");
});
```